# Access through domain name is slowly and IP accessing is fast

Tags: iis

We published a site which works on IIS, but recently we encounted a issue, it is very slow if user access site through domainname but fast with IP.
We finally solved it by change the web server DNS address.

What I don't know is what is the root cause? Why the server dns makes this issue?

Comment: "We finally solved it by change the web server DNS address." What exactly did you do? Changing the CNAME record?

Comment: I changed the DNS server address in web server, the original DNS server is invalid in that time.